# use DataTables only for exporting (pdf and excel)

Tags: angularjs, datatables, ng-grid

[DataTables](http://datatables.net/) is fancy library. Yet, the only part that I care about is its "extra" [TableTool](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) which provides a very easy and useful buttons to export the data table to pdf, excel, csv, and print.

In my framework I depend on **angularjs**, I have my own grid, and I also use **ng-grid**. 
So, I want to use the *TableTool* extra only. ng-grid (or my own grid) can be the data source for *DataTables* plugin (json also available). But I don't want *datatables* to meddle with my grid any furthar than export porpuse.

Any ideas?

Comment: see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894356/exporting-ng-grid-data-to-csv-and-pdf-format-in-angularjs. Personally I always prefer server side solutions where have more control over output formatting. There are however numerous plugins for converting with javascript